# Parallelize recursive function with OpenMP v.2.0

Tags: c++, recursion, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize parts of a project that relies on a lot of recursive algorithms.

Most of them are some form of binary tree creation or traversal and processing.

I'm stuck using GCC v. 4.1.2 on RedHat and the VC++ compiler on Windows (both don't support OpenMP 3.0 with its convenient `task` construct).
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023135/c-openmp-parallel-quicksort) which seems to get the job done with nested parallel sections and some throttling to prevent an exorbitant number of threads.

My question: any way to avoid this approach? Some of the functions are called at each timestep, the overhead of repeatedly creating and destroying a thread team is unacceptable.

Here's the basic structure of a recursive function I've been using, in line with the linked question:

```cpp
extern int threads;
omp_set_nested(1); omp_set_num_threads(2);
void cell::updateRecursive() {

    // do stuff for cell for this timestep

   #pragma omp flush(threads)
   if (threads>=omp_get_num_procs()) {
       child0->updateRecursive(); child1->updateRecursive(); // no new threads
   } else {
       #pragma omp atomic
       threads++;
       #pragma omp flush(threads)
       #pragma omp parallel sections nowait
       {
           #pragma omp seciton
           child0->updateRecursive();
           #pragma omp section
           child1->updateRecursive();
       }
       #pragma omp atomic
       threads--;
   }
}
```

This would be sufficient if this function weren't called so often.
I'd like a way to recurse that can use an existing team of threads to perform work, rather than creating one while traversing the tree.

Would this be possible at all without `task`? I've experimented with simply using `sections`, but apparently they can't be nested to use an existing team of threads.

Comment: There are options (I thought it was the default) to have threads not be destroyed but wait and be recycled when needed again.

Comment: I tried explicitly setting `OMP_WAIT_POLICY=active` but unfortunately that [isn't recognized by VC++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sfk977f%28v=vs.110%29).

Comment: Microsoft's OpenMP runtime uses thread pools. `libgomp` also implements its own thread pool on top of POSIX threads. Still there is a lot of overhead in managing the regions themselves. Perhaps you should look into other programming models like TBB.